# Is it absolutely insulating in its interior of topological insulator?

Tags: dielectric, topological-insulators, insulators

If putting a 3D topological insulator (TI) into a sandwich testing structure (electrode-TI-electrode), can we detect any leakage current in its interior like the ordinary insulator? Is it absolutely insulating in its interior? If we incerease the testing electric field high enough, can the TI break down like the ordinary insulator? Thank you guys for your replies.

Cheers:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although topological insulators are perfect insulators with zero bulk conductivity *in theory*, they are not in most experiments. Usually, there are residual impurities in the bulk causing a finite density of states and some degree of conductivity.

Even a perfect TI could allow for tunneling, if made thin enough. One manifestation of this is the coupling of opposite topological surface states. The cause of this is the finite extent of surface states into the bulk. They are bound to the surface, but have a (energy-dependent) decay length into the bulk.

Comment: Many thanks :) Does it mean that, in a ideal TI, there is no displacement current (the polorization process) or conduction current (conductivity), if we leave out tunneling? How about the interface between the surface and bulk of TI? Would there be space charge like that between orinary insulation and electrode? I am really confused... Thanks.

Comment: @JoeZZ: I added the statement of zero bulk conductivity for ideal TIs to my answer, and some information about the spatial extent of surface states.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much. TI is fascinating which will be widely used in engineering. I really want to vote your answer, but I am sorry I have only 6 reputation... Anyway, thanks a lot.

Comment: @JoeZZ: you can still accept my answer as valid by clicking below the up-/downvote button.

Comment: sorry to bother you again, but a question is following. As the surface of 3D TI is conducting, is the electric field present in the bulk when the applied field is perpendicular to the surface? Would the surface be like a shielding layer to prevent the electromagnetic waves? Be grateful for your patience.

Comment: @JoeZZ: if you apply an external but static electric field, then the surface states will tend to screen the field. The screening ability of any 2D system depends on its density of states at the Fermi energy. If the density of states is high, external fields are screened more strongly than if it is low. Especially close to the Dirac point, the density of states is very small (ideally zero), and screening is very bad. For EM waves you have to consider dynamic screening, which is a bit more complicated.

Comment: Right, thanks a lot. It gives some new ideas for my study.